# Norway - Why do all the school children wear red jumpsuits?

Tags: local-customs, study, clothing, norway

I travelled to Norway a month ago, and whilst there I noticed that all the school children wore red jumpsuits. I thought that this seemed quite distinctive and wondered why this was - perhaps it is more practical in the cold weather?

Comment: Could you specify when "a month ago" was, for future reference?

Comment: If you begin with "Not strictly a question about travel", you are asking for someone to VTC your question :-D I edited it, hope it's fine for you.

Comment: P.S. I love the "perhaps it is more practical in the cold weather", 'cause it sounds like "hey, maybe the red make the kids easier to find" :-D

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBm3Gwx38Po&feature=youtu.be&t=123

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about travel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A month ago would have been the time of [Russefeiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russefeiring).

> The russefeiring traditionally starts on around 20 April and ends on 17 May, the Norwegian Constitution day. **Participants wear coloured overalls**, they make groups and name a bus, car or van and celebrate almost continually during this period.
>
> There are several different types of russ differing in the colour of the caps and traditional uniforms most students carry during the entire russ period. The colour of the uniforms usually reflects what type of study the person is completing. However, in some regions such as Stavanger, the colour is determined by the school. Typically in these areas, if the headmaster of the school was a blue russ, the students will also be blue regardless of what they are studying.

So this is a special celebration, not an all-year uniform. Only those graduating high school (18 years old) take part, and some students will be wearing colours other than red. The colour may indicate the area of study, or the school.

Comment: Are you sure that this is what the OP is referring to? He is specifically referring to 'all the school *children*'. Students are only participating in the russ celebration in their last year in upper secondary school (13th class), where the students are usually 18 or 19 years old. Of course it depends on the point of view, but I would not refer to these as *children*.

Comment: I'm not sure. It seems like a plausible explanation, and the accepted mark seems to back it up. I've edited to make it explicit that it's 18 year olds. If the OP thinks this doesn't match, like if he saw young children in these overalls, then I'd suggest he remove the acceptance tick.

Answer (score 3):

This may be the wrong answer, but if it is a bright red, it could be the same reason German schoolchildren are wearing high-visibility jackets on excursions:

[image]

While unusual 10 years before, it is now a normal sight in Germany. Because children are often spontanous and impulsive, they could do some dangerous tomfoolery even under supervision. It also helps to see if one is falling back behind the group and as car driver you really see them miles away.

Comment: It also tells children that walking on the street is dangerous, which parents might aprove off. But on the other hand, most streets are way safer than in previous years and kids are allowed to use them less and less.